# Why does Stack Exchange use separate databases for each network site?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions, network-profile, performance, database-design

There are reasonable reasons for why separate sites are appropriate for Stack Exchange according to what it aims to be, and some of them are discussed here : [Why is Stack Exchange split into multiple sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64367/why-is-stackexchange-split-into-multiple-sites)

But my question is about separate databases used for each site. (It is mentioned in several questions of the network that SE uses separate databases for each single site )
Are there any performance/maintainability/extensibility/etc reason behind using separate databases that I haven't noticed, or it's just because of backward compatibility?

I ask this because it seems to be preferable that some tables like `Post` be centralized in one DB, So generating some stuff like *Hot network questions*, *Top questions of each user in his network profiles*, etc would be simpler and less resource consuming.

**Update:** As I mentioned in the comments, splitting databases into multiple ones for performance tuning is not acceptable and the standard alternatives here are replication and sharding. I ask you, if there are billions of records in a table, do you break it into multiple SQL tables or use a solution like partitioning? with multiplying the database, you just make maintainability and change management of schema harder and it is not a correct choice from a SQA perspective.

Furthermore, the amount of data and number of reads/writes vary from site to site tremendously. For instance, SO has more than 8 million questions, while some sites has only about 1 thousand and don't seem to grow much in future. So it is another reason for that multiplying the database is not good idea for performance tuning.

Comment: Putting everything in one database would severely hurt performance, because it vastly increases the amount of data and load on a single server. Why would you want posts related to use of the English language or cooking dumped into the same database as [so] questions? Not dumping unrelated data into the same table (or database) is basic normalization. Just because they're all under the [se] umbrella doesn't mean they're the same thing.

Comment: For the live site, which has many many reads and writes that you want to be lightning-fast, separate databases make sense for the reasons Ken said. For analytics (like SEDE), having it all in one DB would allow you to write cross-site queries without some of the kludges I've seen (and who cares if your query takes a few seconds, or even a few tens of seconds, to run?). But maintaining two different DB architectures, one for operations and one for SEDE, is probably too much work for too little perceived gain.

Comment: For performance? So why put Stack Overflow in one db and a tiny site like Beer in another? Are they equivalent in size and number of reads/writes? With your idea, why not splitting SO db in multiple databases?  As I know, because performance is not the only factor and for example changing schema and monitoring databases are some of other factors, there are solutions like `replication` and `sharding` which are introduced for such problems like performance, and making the database multiple doesn't make sense with the aim of performance tuning.

Comment: Suppose unix.SE crashed and others didn't. You have to restore the database and then you would lose others in the process.

Comment: Dumping stuff in different, identical, databases is basic *denormalisation* @Ken. Of you had a powerful enough cluster and partition by site then there should be little difference having it all in one, and a lot less maintenance. I assume the reason may be related to money, an active-active SQL Server cluster with partitioning doesn't come cheap.

Comment: You started out by asking a reasonable question: why does SE use separate DBs?  You've now turned it into an argument for why you think that's wrong, which sounds more like a feature request.  Which is it -- do you want to know the reasons, or do you want to convince people that SE's architecture is wrong?

Comment: @MonicaCellio: Of course I'm asking about the reasons, but the questioner always has his own beliefs in his mind and that's why a question comes in. additionally, I updated my question to mention my comment which was in response to others' comments and this would help the process of discussion. _no feature is requested here_, we are just talking about what's going on.

Comment: You wrote that it's "basic normalisation" @ken, hence my comment. Assuming it's related to money then we seem agree, though I'm not sure that you understand still. Your last comment states that _"There's no justification here for mingling the data across site, therefore no justification for denormalizing the data."_, which is a contradiction.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: You're right. I didn't catch my misstatement. My comment was in error (both times). I should pay more attention. :-) I really do know the difference. <g>

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Oh, *loads* of reasons:

- the number of times we need to query data for multiple sites *at the same time* is ridiculously low - like, a fraction of a percent
- the per-site data is a natural partition, allowing us to split a whole range of maintenance tasks like backup, indexing, etc
- we don't need to include an extra join / filter in **every single query**
- it allows the database server to have appropriate per-site statistics with the minimum overhead
- it allows us to spread **and balance** the load arbitrarily between physical servers
- which means we can scale out rather than up
- and at a lower level, between disks etc
- it allows us to spin up a new site easily, and have the identifiers (user-ids/etc) make sense without extra work
- and to remove an entire failing site in one go, without having to do expensive work

But perhaps the most obvious answer: stackoverflow was built first, and had no concept of multiple sites. When it came to adding meta, superuser and serverfault etc (the next 3), the choices were:

- use parallel databases
- revisit, validate and/or rewrite **every single line of code** to handle logical databases

But even without that: it works great... So why *wouldn't* we go for multi-database?

You say:

> I ask this because it seems to be preferable that some tables like Post be centralized in one DB, So generating some stuff like Hot network questions, Top questions of each user in his network profiles, etc would be simpler and less resource consuming.

I say: it isn't a problem to us. We solve actual, real problems - with zeal and gusto. This isn't something that causes us pain, so why would be focus all our energy on that one feature? Why bend the system out of shape to fix a non-problem?

You also say:

> As I mentioned in the comments, splitting databases into multiple ones for performance tuning is not acceptable and the standard alternatives here are replication and sharding.

Here I have to look sideways at you. We do all sorts of bizarre things for performance. Now, as it happens there are lots of other good reasons *besides* performance to do this, but frankly: performance **by itself** would absolutely, without question, be a valid reason to do this.

Performance is a feature. For us, it is a **major** feature. We worry about performance *a lot*.

Yes, sharding is a thing, but then you need to have all associated data on the same shard for useful queries to work. The site is a natural logical shard-point. So why not use the site as the shard?