# Is splitting Stack Exchange into tiny sub sites really the direction we should be taking?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, scope

> *Didn't someone already ask that?* Yes, something like this has been asked and I'll provide a link for you right here, before you have to
>   go looking for duplicates:
>   [Why is Stack Exchange split into multiple sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64367/why-is-stack-exchange-split-into-multiple-sites/64373#64373)
>   In that case the OP asked about **why** there are so many splits.
>   *This isn't my question.*

My concern is not so much about providing more sub-sites, but the way overlapping questions are handled right now. It appears every site moderator just keeps looking to find something wrong with the next question or answer she can find and will vote to close the entire thing or at least down vote it.

I understand if its really off-topic, sure close it, shut it down, make it go away, but if it's just not fitting perfectly into someones own expectation of what this exact site should be about, but other people appear to happily exchange knowledge there anyway - telling them off and closing their topics appears counterproductive and doesn't help anyone.

For example there is a site about **Earth Science** and one about **Outdoors**, one about **Travel** and another about **Aviation**, one for **Health**, one for **Fitness**, one for **Sports**, one for **DIY home improvement** and one for **Crafts** and one for **Lifehacks**.

Yes, these categories can be differentiated, but not all questions will fit exactly into one of them or can easily be asked on multiple boards at the same time (my point here).

Just like we don't have one site for **Python**, one for **C++**, one for **Java**, how can we justify having one site for **Academia**, but another one for **Biology** and another one for **Physics** and a third for **Chemistry** and another one for **Mathematics**?

What is the guy with a question about chemical equations regarding his biology experiment going to do? First, he'll try in Biology, because, you know, that's his comfort zone, but he'll be directed to go somewhere else. Then he'll try in chemistry, where he'll be told it's too mathematical a question. Then he'll try in Mathematics, where someone things this is all about general science.

See, topics can not just be categorised into small little sections and split that way - it's insane - there are interdisciplinary questions everywhere and the current direction Stack Exchange is taking is killing them off.

Yes, you can vote down and close this one, too, since it's becoming more of a complaint than a question, but I sincerely hope someone will please turn this around and see that Stack Exchange was all about bringing people together and not splitting and disecting them into smaller and smaller categories.

Don't get me wrong - I love Stack Exchange - I just don't love when people disregard valid and well written answers or questions, because they don't fit into their exact topic expectation.

Please let me know if you disagree (I am sure many people will) and why?
And if you need a proper question:

**Is splitting Stack Exchange into tiny sub-sites really the direction we should be taking?**

My suggestion is simple - just have bigger categories - merge those sub-sites, maybe even better:

**Why not allow the users to vote to merge one Stack Exchange site into another?**
I think this would be fair and the right approach, because it'll be a community decision, by the people who actually want to use these sites.

Comment: "_Self-installed forum leader_": actually, pro-tem moderators are chosen by SE staff, and once the site has graduated, the moderators are chosen by community votes.

Comment: Yes, I'm not referring to actual moderators, but common users, who usually gained some reputation on the forum and now think they need to take these matters into their own hands

Comment: **[Stack Exchange is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92107/is-stack-overflow-a-forum)**.

Comment: You're mostly making comparisons of the sites based on their short names, not their actual content. For example, ["Aviation Stack Exchange is a site for pilots, controllers, mechanics, and aviation enthusiasts."](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) whereas ["Travel Stack Exchange is for road warriors and seasoned travelers"](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Look at their "on topic" lists. There's no overlap. The same goes for Academia. That's about _working_ in a scholastic setting. It has nothing whatsoever to do with the study  of biology or physics.

Comment: There's no shared expertise between the sites that you've grouped.

Comment: "*What is the guy with a question about chemical equations regarding his biology experiment going to do? First, he'll try in Biology, because, you know, that's his comfort zone, but he'll be directed to go somewhere else. Then he'll try in chemistry, where he'll be told it's too mathematical a question. Then he'll try in Mathematics, where someone things this is all about general science.*" then the question is too broad. If it's already specific and having main topicality, I don't think there will be problem, like chemical reaction in Biology would be happily answered by Biology experts.

Comment: Also, [site creation is already a community process](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/), supervised by SE. If there's a need to merge sites, then the former is considered a failure.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I know they try to be distinct, but I don't think they should, because more often than not the aviation enthusiast may travel somewhere - I'm sure there are plenty of so called off-topic questions on any of those pages, making my point that this is not a user-friendly environment, if I constantly have to be concerned that someone is going to just close my topic - people will stop using these sites and that can't be in the interest of stackexchange?

Comment: @JonW yes, that is a good thing and some distinction is required, but do you really only want to bring together highly specialized experts of certain fields? I think that's for the community to decide. Clearly by this logic you'd have to make as many small SEs as possible, which will absolutely limit the questions you can ask on SE in general. I think limiting questions will lead to less relevance and ultimately failure...

Comment: @AndrewT. That only works if the majority of users would already be engaged at that early point of creation, but they are simply not- they will find the site later and start using it...

Comment: @Chris Yes, I really *do* want to bring specialised experts together. Otherwise we'd be Yahoo Answers.  If there are enough potential questions in a specific field, and enough experts in that field then absolutely, it should a separate site.

Comment: Do you suggest that Lego, Biology, SciFi and Stack Overflow should merge?

Comment: As for merging sites - never might the technical/social issues (and glossing over what it would do to google ranks), if two sites think they want/should merge, they all have venues to suggest such a thing - on their metas and here. There is absolutely no need to create a voting system for something that will probably never happen for the very large majority of sites.

Comment: @Oded yes, I'm glad you brought that up

Comment: Can you be more specific? I gave two different comments that brought different things up.

Comment: And here my passing curiosity is whether [so] is _too large_, and if some of its larger parts should start to form their own communities.

Comment: @arthurfischer I would be delighted to hear what the problem about a large community, such as stackoverflow is ? You have tags to classify questions and I for one don't see how it could benefit anyone to separate even further?

Comment: I would even argue, if stackoverflow would have been as strict as all those beta sites are now, it would have never gotten as popular as it is today and that would have been a huge loss for all programmers in my opinion. A more open and less restrictive approach will encourage questions - some people think there are wrong questions (like this one), but I'll disagree. I think the size of stackoverflow may sometimes make it a little unpredictable, but it also brings different expertise together, which some people don't want, but I deem necessary to be able to create truly inspiring answers.

Comment: since I'm at 8 down-votes with 6 distinct people commenting, I guess my question must absolutely be off topic and incomprehensible :D

Comment: @Oded don't take everything so serious - I was being sarcastic and your second post - that I actually consider useful - hadn't shown up while I was typing ...

Comment: Downvoting on meta is different: http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta

Comment: "Why not allow the users to vote to merge one Stack Exchange site into another?" Interestingly, this did happen once. The communities of Unix & Linux and AskUbuntu, two sites with _significant_ overlap, were [asked to vote on merging their sites](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/should-unix-linux-and-ubuntu-be-merged-vote/). Can you guess what both communities decided?

Comment: @Oded voting is not that different according to your link, except for feature-request. Now, of course you can think of this as a feature-request, if you want to, but I just wanted to have a discussion.

Comment: @Yannis - actually it seems one of the votes was in favour of merging and one against... https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhLcW.png But to be honest - 200 people voting 6 years ago is hardly a representative vote - you have thousands of members on those sites and less than 1% of people participate back then. It seems that vote should really be re-done (maybe every 4 years or so).

Comment: @Yannis - also, the "larger" community voted in favour, while the smaller voted against, which makes sense - why not make a single stack exchange site for every linux distribution out there - just my exact same point regarding programming languages - it'll be madness - you'll have duplicate posts everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It is the right way as Stack Exchange is basically a group of sites, with each site designated to one subject.

In cases users do not quite know where to post a question due to the fact it fits in multiple subjects, users can ask here at MSE to determine the right site for that question. With multiple high rep users from all over the SE network, there is bound for someone to recognize that question to be well-received in a site.

Now if you combine every site into bigger categories, it may take while to  ale the site, migrate thousands of posts to that site, etc. Making bigger categories is unnecessary and not wise. As we have experts and those who know about a related subject, it is better not to make a big category.

Comment: I agree with you on the "you can always ask on meta" argument, but not a lot of new users know that (I didn't for a long time). You area also ignoring my points about how fragmentation will make it harder to ask questions of interdisciplinary nature. *Where does the Biophysics student turn to?*